# CSS not affecting link

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that uses navigation with two lines of text. These are identified using span. The first span is responding to changes in the CSS, in particular a:hover, but the smaller text isn't responding.

I'm simply looking to change the colour of the smaller text when hovering, and to understand what I'm not doing or doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

[Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/G4f6u/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very subtle solution to your problem. You currently have:

```
#navigation .pagetitle a:hover{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: orange;
}
```

But this would be where the anchor was a child of the span. It's actually the other way around...

```
#navigation a:hover .pagetitle{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the :hover applied to the a tag, when it should be applied to the span tag. Like so: 
`#navigation .pagetitle:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Try this decendent selector:

```
#navigation.pagetitle {
font-size: 15px;
color: #999;
```

}

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I see no descendant selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#navigation a:hover span{
    color: #ec0181;
    background-color: #333;    
}
```

Comment: That colors both the spans the same, not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the **!important** feature. Example:

```
#navigation .pagetitle a:hover{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: orange !important;
}
```